# Error creating new order from Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-order-create

I'm getting this in Total Orders section when I'm on the Create New Order page

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function setTotals() on a non-object in /home/pixelsp0/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Totals.php on line 77"

[image]

What it could be?

---

edit:

@kunz

```
<sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <giantpoints_renderer_point>
                    <class>giantpoints/total_quote_renderer_point</class>
                    <before>nominal,subtotal</before>
                    <renderer>giantpoints/checkout_cart_renderer_point</renderer>
                    <admin_renderer>giantpoints/adminhtml_checkout_cart_renderer_point</admin_renderer>
                </giantpoints_renderer_point>
                <giantpoints_spending_before_tax>
                    <class>giantpoints/total_quote_spending_beforeTax</class>
                    <after>discount</after>
                    <before>tax</before>
                </giantpoints_spending_before_tax>
                <giantpoints_spending_after_tax>
                    <class>giantpoints/total_quote_spending_afterTax</class>
                    <after>tax</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </giantpoints_spending_after_tax>
            </totals>
        </quote>
```

So I found the extension that is in conflict: Mage giant Points. For some reason, it's in my local and not community.
I don't understand what exactly is going on after `<totals>`, I have watched quite an old (2012) 20 hour course online, but now I realized Magento even in version 1 has changed a few things (or this is what it looks like to me). Shouldn't he be specifying a `<rewrite>` tag in order to rewrite? Can you help me understand what is going on just by looking thing short XML?

```
    class Magegiant_GiantPoints_Model_Total_Quote_Renderer_Point
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCode('giantpoints_renderer_point');
    }

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        // Init Giant Points
        $address->setGiantpointsSpent(0);
        $address->setGiantpointsBaseDiscount(0);
        $address->setGiantpointsDiscount(0);
        $address->setGiantpointsEarn(0);

        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $address->addTotal(array(
            'code'  => $this->getCode(),
            'title' => '1',
            'value' => 1,
        ));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

is the `giantpoints/total_quote_renderer_point` `Point.php` file.

Comment: Magento could not get object/method. Like this, you have called `$object->setTotals({{some peram}})`  and magento could not get `$object` as PHP object  or `setTotals` method is not there in that `$object`.

Comment: @kunj Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain a bit more since I have just started using Magento.

Comment: If you have not customized Magento admin total then it is rendering total from this file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Totals.php`
From this function :

`protected function _getTotalRenderer($code)`

You can see `$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($block, $blockName);` in that function Magento creating all total's object. try to debug it. Your can also check any module have this type of code:
`<sales><quote><totals>{{some xml code}}</totals></quote></sales>`

Comment: @kunj I just edited my initial question. Could you please have a look and let me know?

Comment: Is this `giantpoints/total_quote_renderer_point` file exist? I hope that module enabled and please share full content or module so investigate on it.

Comment: @kunj yeah it does exist under model. That's why I was not able to call it since it wasn't even a block. Now I am curious about its purpose. You can see the file in my original question.

Comment: Please share that module. And try to disable/comment that code one by one and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was dead simple: disable the module not working! In this case Magegiant Refer one was having issues here and overall as well. Since it was really buggy, I completely disabled it from app/code/etc/modules/... since disabling it from Magento webpage was not working at all.